# How to pass variable to another component react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass variable from one component to another one
like

```js
const filter = () => {
  const value ="test"
  return (<H1>you are watching test</h1>)
}
```

and want to use value variable in this component

```js
const home = () => {
  return (<H1>you are watching {value}</h1>)
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a value from children to parent like that:

First solution by passing function  from parent to children component:
Children:

```
const home = ({setValue})=>{ 
SetValue(x)
return (<H1>Home</h1>)
}
```

Parent

```
const [value٫setValue] = useState()
const filter = ()=>{
return (<Home setValue={setValue}/>)
```

Second solution by using a global state management system like Context, Redux or Recoil...

Answer (score 1):

First solution by passing props from parent to children component:
Children:

```
const home = ({value})=>{ 
return (<H1>you are watching {value}</h1>)
}
```

Parent

```
const filter = ()=>{
const value ="test"
return (<Home value={value}/>)
```

}

Second solution by using a global state menagement like Redux, Recoil, Context...

Comment: what if i want to pass from child to parent